GrapesJs with MJML How to edit Text on Buttons
I'm using GrapesJS for the first time along with the MJML plugin. I've been adding custom blocks, and everything seems to be working fine until I realized that I can't edit the text of the buttons directly on the canvas. I've also noticed that this functionality is not available on the project's demo page either.
Is there a way to make the text of the buttons editable? I've tried different configurations with 'editable', but none seem to work. For example:
export const BTN_AQUA = { label: 'Btn aqua', category: 'basics', type: 'mj-button', editable: true, draggable: true, stylable: true, selectable: true, content:  <mj-button background-color="#028484" color="white"> Button </mj-button>, }
Also I've tried a workaround by creating a text component that looks like a button and contains an anchor with the text. However, the problem arises when editing the text; if I delete it entirely to write something else, the anchor element is lost completely, and it just write normal text.
Any help is appreciated
